# Wordpress frontend on HTTPS, backend on HTTP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

Is it possible to setup .htaccess for Wordpress to run Frontend over https protocol, and admin backend over http protocol?

Comment: Is the frontend decoupled from the backend?

Comment: Hhhmm, just curious... why? If anything, it's the opposite of what you would normally want to do.

Comment: Since migrating to HTTPS there one issue that i can't solve. Image upload is all-ways stuck on 100% "crunching..." and async-upload.php returns 403 error code. But we didnt change any permissions on upload folder and i also tried to set it to 777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea. When in the non-SSL backend you will end adding http images, which will then make unsecure your frontend.

To be fully SSL-compatible, you should run both with this protocol.

Comment: Thanks for info. Must admit it was bad idea in the first place.